# Jupyter / iPython; No connection to kernel; 0 active kernels

Tags: kernel, anaconda, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run Jupyter/iPython in Chrome on Windows 7. I followed some online instructions and installed latest Anaconda. Then ran:

`jupyter notebook`

Then I opened a new notebook but couldn't get connected to kernel (as per info in the notebook and lack of possibility to execute any code). Here is the screen shot with the Developer view of my Chrome:

[Kernel busy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQyKQ.png)

It keeps saying 'Kernel busy'. I tried to do the same without firewall and antivirus but no results unfortunately. Would be great if you could share your knowledge / experience on that matter.

Regards
MaJ

Comment: Could you provide some more details? It seems that just knowing you run `jupyter notebook --debug` probably won't be enough for others to reproduce your issue and help you with it.

Comment: Hi Wai, I edited my initial post as managed to sort out the first problem, however still can't connect to kernel so attached 2 screenshots to provide more clrity. Cheers, MaJ

Comment: 'Terminals not available' is normal on Windows, and '0 active kernels' is normal for when you start the notebook server. If you have any security software, try temporarily turning it off - we've had problems in the past with programs like Sophos blocking the connection.

Comment: Hi, I ran the whole process again from scratch. Uninstalled and reinstalled anaconda, uninstalled all my antivirus software and switched off my firewall. Then ran `jupyter notebook`. The browser worked fine and opened the notebook but in this case it says 'Kernel busy'. Would the output of my terminal help here ? Thanks.